# jquery slide work only firefox not chrome, opera, ie

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

i have just wrote a simple slider. But there is something strange and I couldn't fix it. The script works in **firefox (12)** and not with;
  **crome  (23.0.1271.64 m),
  opera  (12.02),
  ie     (7-8-9-D),
  safari (5.1.7).**

Here is the code below. Can anyone tell me how i can i fix it?

### [jsfiddle code.](http://jsfiddle.net/v7aMT/21/)

```
$.fn.etkinlikslide = function() {
    var etkinlikid        = this.selector.replace(/\#/g,'');
    var esheight    = parseInt($('#'+etkinlikid).height());
    var epheight    = parseInt($('#etkinlikpanel').height());
    function oynat(){
        var topcheck =parseInt($('#'+etkinlikid).css("top"))+parseInt($('#'+etkinlikid).height());
        if (topcheck<0) $('#'+etkinlikid).css("top",$('#etkinlikpanel').css("height"));
        $('#'+etkinlikid).css("top",parseInt($('#'+etkinlikid).css("top"))-1+'px');
    }
    if (esheight>epheight) {
        var etkinliktimer = window.setInterval(function() {oynat()}, 80);
        $('#'+etkinlikid).hover(function(){
            window.clearInterval(etkinliktimer);
        },function(){
            etkinliktimer = window.setInterval(function() {oynat()}, 80);
        });
    }
};
$("#etkinlikslide").etkinlikslide();
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what the problem is?

Comment: the #etkinlikslide div should slide up but it works only in firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the default for CSS property top is set to auto in IE where as it is 0 in Firefox.

So the function 
`var topcheck =parseInt($('#'+etkinlikid).css("top"))+parseInt($('#'+etkinlikid).height());` fails as it returns NaN.

Adding top: 0; in your CSS to the div would solve it

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/v7aMT/27/)